# Elementary Java Algorithm Assistance

Tags: java, algorithm

I need help writing a program that is given a specified number of coordinate points in the form (X,Y). The number of points that will be given is the first line in the program; it can be read in through a scanner.

I need to calculate the least amount of area to cover all of the points with the lines x = a, and y = b. So, the area would be a * b (Area of a rectangle).

However, one coordinate point (X, Y) must be removed to optimize the area. The point that is removed should minimize the area as much as possible. I need help writing algorithm to do so.

This is a sample input, and output that I was given ::

**SAMPLE INPUT**

4

2 4

1 1

5 2

17 25

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

12

---

In this example, the first line of input (4) indicates that four points will be input. The next four lines are the coordinates in form (x, y). The last point which is (17, 25) is removed as the outlier which leaves us with the first three points.

[image: If these three remaining points are graphed]

If the three remaining points are graphed, they can all be inside a box (3 by 4) hence the output is 12; (3 * 4). It is OK for the line to be on the point like in this example. However, the outlier is not always the last point, or very big. The outlier could be very small, the area just needs to be minimized.

--
This is what I have so far (I know it's not very much..) - please help me!

It's mostly just the algorithm that I need help with..

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Area {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numOfPoints = scan.nextInt();
        int Xcoordinates[] = new int[numOfPoints];
        int Ycoordinates[] = new int[numOfPoints];


        for (int i = 0; i <= numOfCows - 1; i++) {
            Xcoordinates[i] = scan.nextInt();
            Ycoordinates[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Possible Pseudocode (continuing from above; this may be wrong..):

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= Xcoordinates.length; i++) { //loop through array 
     compare values, and determine outlier
     int lowestXValue = [find lowest x value]
     int highestXValue = [find highest x value; not outlier] }

     remove xcoordinates[outlier]
     remove ycoordinates[outlier]     

 int xLength = highestXValue - lowestXValue - 1 // -1 because can be on line

 for (int i = 0; i <= Ycoordinates.length; i++) { //loop through y array
      int lowestYValue = [find lowest y value]
      int highestYValue = [find highesy Y value] }

 int yLength = highestYValue - lowestYValue - 1;

 int boxArea = yLength * xLength

 System.out.println(boxArea);
```

---

However, this would only search through the possible X outlier, and if there's a Y value that would minimize area by removal, it would not catch that

Comment: Write some pseudo-code, then convert it to Java, then show it to us.

Comment: I wrote some pseudocode, could you please check it?

Comment: Step through it by hand and see if you get what you want.

Comment: You're doing very well. Fix those cases. I'm impressed that you are working through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create two sorted lists of integers, one for the x co-ords and one for the y co-ords. Then you can check the area saved by removing the max x co-ordinate (area saved should be max y co-ordinate times (max x co-ordinate - second highest x co-ordinate)). You can do the same thing to check the area saved by removing the max y co-ordinate, and whichever is greater will be your final answer.

Comment: First, this is not correct. Sometimes you might need to remove the lowest x/y coordinate in order to minimize the area. Second, you involve sorting into your solution which is `O(log(N))`. This problem can be solved in `O(N)`

Comment: @GA1 You may be correct but in general it is not worth resurrecting a year old thread to comment on an answer the OP never paid any attention to in the first place.